# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS works for main website but not WordpRess installation in /blog/

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am running a website with a WordPress installation contained within a /blog/ subdirectory. The Rewrite rules I have in place currently transform correctly for the main site, but not for the Wordpress install.

```
http://mywebsite.com
```

is transformed to

```
https://www.mywebsite.com
```

without issue.

However, these URLS:

```
http://mywebsite.com/blog/ 
http://mywebsite.com/blog/title-of-article/
```

are not transforming into what I want, which is this:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/ 
https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/title-of-article/
```

Is this a Wordpress issue, or is my .htaccess wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(blog/.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE:**

The new .htaccess, placed in the /blog/ directory, has made some progress.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/$1 [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

So `mywebsite.com/blog/` is being transformed to `https://mywebsite.com/blog/`. Great! `mywebsite.com/blog/article-title/` is being transformed to `https://mywebsite.com/blog/article-title/`. The issue is that the `www.` is not being added. They need to be `https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/article-title`.

Any ideas as to why the `www.` is missing?

**UPDATE 2:**

Turns out I forgot to add the "www." in the default URL in the Wordpress settings (General > Settings > Wordpress URL). With that set to `https://www.example.com/blog/` and the above .htaccess in the /blog/ directory, all is now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to manage rewrite rules separately by directories.

For blog folder, you should add the rewrite rule in .htaccess within blog folder.

If you want server-wide changes, you shouldn't use .htaccess and edit relevant details within the server configuration file.

#### /.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

#### /blog/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When adding .htaccess entries in WordPress directory, note that there is a section that will be automatically overwritten by WordPress.

As long as you place your own rules outside of `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress`, the rules will stay.

Finally, you should also change your WordPress Address and Site Address within the WordPress settings (Settings > General) to use https instead.

Comment: Thanks, it's closer to working now but still not 100%. I added that code to the .htaccess in /blog/ and `http://mywebsite.com/blog/` gets converted to `https://mywebsite.com/blog/`, but the `www`. is not added. Also, the article links (`http://mywebsite.com/blog/article-title/`) are not being converted to anything; they remain unchanged. Any ideas? I have HTTPS enabled in Wordpress.

Comment: @MSOACC Instead of placing the Rewrite block above for /blog/ below the WordPress Rewrite block, try placing it above it. Place it before `# BEGIN WordPress`.